# MS Access with MySQL backend query with two JOINs results in excessive queries

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, odbc

I have 2 tables, `Customers` and `Countries`, like so:

Customers:

```
    +----+------+-----+---------------+----------------+
    | ID | Name | ... | OfficeCountry | BillingCountry |
    +----+------+-----+---------------+----------------+
    | 1  | Bill | ... | 1             | 1              |
    | 2  | Joe  | ... | 2             | 1              |
    +----+------+-----+---------------+----------------+
```

Countries:

```
    +----+-------------+
    | ID | Name        |
    +----+-------------+
    | 1  | USA         |
    | 2  | Netherlands |
    +----+-------------+
```

(I stripped some columns from the `Customers` table to only have some relevant columns for this question)
The purpose of those two columns are that the country for billing and the physical office location could be different. We also have more address information in this table, but stripped for this example.

I `JOIN` these two tables with a query resulting in something like this:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    some, 
    fields,
    Countries_1.Name AS OfficeCountryName,
    Countries_2.Name AS BillingCountryName
    
FROM
    Customers
    
    LEFT JOIN
        Countries AS Countries_1
    ON
        Customers.OfficeCountry = Countries_1.ID    
    
    LEFT JOIN
        Countries AS Countries_2
    ON
        Customers.BillingCountry = Countries_2.ID
```

The application we are using is a MS Access front end with a MySQL back-end. This is done with ODBC.

The `Customers` table contains roughly 15,000 records.

The problem is that the application has a bad performance. I enabled the query log, and I can see the following queries being executed when I am loading the data (from a DynaSet) into a form:

- The Query as written above
- An extra query, with an `OUTER JOIN`, written in the old legacy `{oj ...}` syntax
- **30.000 queries** (2x the COUNT from `Customers`) to the `Countries` table. This exact query: `SELECT ID FROM Countries WHERE ID = 2` (or `ID = 1`, depending on the Customer).

The last two queries amaze me.

1. First, **WHERE is the `OUTER JOIN` query coming from?** I never specified any `OUTER JOIN` in Access. Also, the old legacy `{oj ..}` syntax gives me the feeling that something's up. Also, this query is not needed. I do not use it's data in the Access front end, and I don't know where it's coming from.
2. Second, **WHY is Access query'ing the `Countries` table for every record?** The data isn't needed, and also not helpful. It's only `SELECT`ing the ID which it already knows (as seen in the `WHERE` clause)

As you can imagine, 30,000 queries is greatly slowing down the performance.

I know that it's not good practice to load 15,000 records into one form (with navigation controls and such), but it's a very old legacy application and a lot of work to re-write.

**EDIT**
I see now that for very simple queries, with just a purpose build very clean form, it generates a few queries:

1. A query that selects all ID's (so for the Customer, and twice the JOIN'ed table
2. A query that selects all neccesary fields PER RECORD RETURNED from query 1, FOR EVERY TABLE. So a SELECT  FROM Customers WHERE Id = record_currently_viewed

Comment: Use server-side cursor.

Comment: @Akina could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: Client-side cursor executes the query on the client side - and you see a bunch of queries (client queries each separate value for each separate row and needed column value with according conditions). Server-side cursor sends the query text to DBMS server and receives final rowset.

Comment: @Akina How and where do I change this? Is this is a setting for the query or something?

Comment: `ADODB.Recordset.CursorLocation=adUseServer`.

Comment: @Akina Where do I set this? Note that I am talking with MySQL using ODBC, using linked tables

Comment: What do you use - DAO? ADODB? Jet? else?

Comment: @Akina We use DAO when using VB, but data access is done using the linked tables and forms with queries behind them as recordset.

Comment: I don't remember how to specify server-side cursor in DAO... try to search for this.

Comment: To fix the 30K queries:  Jettison Excel.  Use some programming language as the frontend to MySQL.  Then you can write that single `SELECT` to do the task.

Comment: Hi, i havent tested in your case but somtimes subquery better than left join and your query is proper for using subquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access queries with multiple LEFT JOINs on linked ODBC tables are notorious for bad performance. The MySql ODBC driver may be even worse than the Sql Server driver, if it fails on such a simple query.

How to fix:

1- In this particular case, there really should be no reason to use LEFT JOIN at all. How can there be country FKs without matching countries?

You should fix any orphaned FKs and create relationships with referential integrity, then use INNER JOIN, and the problem will be gone.

2- If this isn't possible, move the processing to the server. Create a View that does the joining, link it in Access, and base the form on it.

3- If you can't modify the backend DB at all, you can also use a PassThrough query. This will be read-only though.

Comment: In my example I indeed used a LEFT JOIN, since the queries are generated that way in the application currently. Changing them to INNER JOIN's doesn't help tho. The queries are still executed excessivly. Option 2 and 3 (Views and PassThrough Queries) are not really an option, since they are read only. This is a very old application, so changing all the forms to use extra code for changing values and changing the calling query would be very time consuming and error prone. I have the feeling this is just some setting or weird behavior I currently do not grasp.

Comment: If INNER JOIN shows the same behavior, there is something very strange going on in your database. It definitely shouldn't. Make sure that Access recognizes all PKs of all linked tables. (Check design view for the "key" icon) -- If you specify the PK (customer ID) when linking a view, it is editable in Access. @NiekvanderSteen

Comment: Did you check both items I wrote above? @NiekvanderSteen

Comment: I did check the above. And indeed, MS Access does *NOT* recognize the FK's. Manually adding them in the 'Relationships' window doesn't seem to help either. @Andre

Comment: I meant the primary keys (PKs). Access never knows about foreign keys in linked ODBC tables, but that shouldn't matter. Adding them in the Relationships window only serves as hint for the Access query designer to create these joins by default when adding the tables to a query.

Comment: Access does indeed recognize the PKs. The key symbol is visible. I also put some indices on columns that are used to link to another table. Like in my example the Country ID from 'OfficeCountry'.

Comment: I tried the same on SQL Server (exported the entire MySQL database to SQL Server), and I see the same result (same query, same amount)

Comment: That is extremely strange. If you run **only** the simple query with INNER JOINs, without a form - does it still happen? @NiekvanderSteen

Comment: The other item I was referring to: linked views **are** editable if you specify the PK when linking.

Answer (score 0):

Have created a small fiddle where you still could use Left join - [With SQL example](https://dbfiddle.uk/nJtD5rVf).

You can try to use with statement - than should load data in memory for further processing:

```
with memCountry (ID, Name) as (select ID, Name from Countries) 
select cu.ID, cu.Name, c1.Name, c2.Name from Customer cu
left join memCountry c1 on cu.OfficeCountry = c1.id
left join memCountry c2 on cu.BillingCountry = c2.id
```